# How do I get past the confirmation prompt to confirm deleting a pyenv env?

Tags: macos, terminal, pyenv

I'm having trouble confirming that I want to delete a pyenv environment. I have tried deleting it with both `pyenv virtualenv-delete <env>` and `pyenv uninstall <env>`. In both cases I'm getting a confirmation prompt for deleting the venv, but I can't figure out the correct key input to confirm:
`pyenv-virtualenv: remove <env>? (y/N)`

I've tried `y` (nothing happens and I can continue typing), Enter (which is recorded as `^M`), Shift + Enter (which is recorded as `^M`), `:`, and Esc (which is recorded as `^[`).

I'm on a mac and am using Terminal and zsh.

Answer (score 0):

I tried restarting my terminal and was able to confirm deletion with `y` + `Enter`